# SQL queries in ASP.NET Web API with Entity Framework and viewing results in Angular 7 component

Tags: sql-server, angular, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

My purpose is to get the result of my SQL query via Web API and use it on my Angular project. But I couldn't be able to figure it out. I don't have so much experience in this field but I will try to explain what I am trying to achieve.

This is my query I wrote in SQL Server:

```
SELECT dbo.Course.CID
FROM dbo.Course
INNER JOIN dbo.Student ON dbo.Course.CID = dbo.Student.CourseID
WHERE Sname = 'DemoTestStudent'
```

What I want to do is create a method in my `StudentController` in my Web API project as follows:

Pseudo method

```
    public GetStudentCourses()
    {
        sql = "My sql query here"
        
        return result(sql)
    }
```

And I want to use this on my Angular project like normal Http operations.

I am sorry if doesn't makes sense but I need help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use httpClient in angular to send a request. You can check this link:
https://angular.io/guide/http just follow the steps. You will be able to learn observables too.